# При перезагрузке страницы объект "PHP" не удаляется

Tags: php, переменные, переопределение

Такая проблема: когда пользователь изменяет электронную почту, на странице появляется сообщение, в котором указывается результат операции. Проблема в том, что при перезагрузке страницы сообщение не исчезает. Я так понимаю, что нужно как-то переменную ("сообщение") обнулить при перезагрузке, но никак не найду способ (session_unregister - это ведь не подходит), хотя в начале всего кода стоит, что переменная пустая.

```
<?php
$mes = "";
$email = $row['Email'];
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["Newemail"])) {
    $mes = "Адрес не может быть пустым";
    echo $mes;
  }
  else {
    $email = edit_mail($_POST["Newemail"]);             
    // Добавление эл. почты в БД
    $result = mysql_query ("UPDATE users SET Email='$email' WHERE Login='".$_SESSION['login']."' AND Password='".$_SESSION['password']."'");
    // Проверяем, получилось ли записать адрес
    if ($result=='TRUE') {
      $mes = "Почта успешно изменена";
       echo $mes;
     }
     else {
       $mes = "Почту изменить не удалось";
       echo $mes;
     }
   }
}
function edit_mail($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;        
}
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
          <label>Электронная почта</label>
            <?php echo $email; ?>   
            <!-- Ввод нового адреса -->            
               <input class="form-control" type="email">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Ок</button>
<?php echo $mes;?>  
        </form>
```

Comment: некорректно сравнение `if ($result=='TRUE')`, правильно - `if ($result)` или  `if ($result === true)`

Comment: Спасибо за замечание!  Жаль, что это не поможет в решении вопроса.

Comment: @Visman, что-то я связь между вопросами не уловил..

Comment: @Qwertiy, связь в том, что в обоих вопросах после принятия post-запроса, следует делать переадресацию методом get, иначе при обновлении страницы в браузере по F5 форма снова будет отправлена.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При обновлении страницы (Ctrl + R) форма отправляется заново.
Раз вы уже знаете как работать с сессиями, то попробуйте при успешном изменении e-mail писать сообщение об успехе в $_SESSION а потом перенаправляйте пользователя на эту же страницу `header('location: ?')`
Соответственно, на самой странице вне зависимости от метода запроса надо проверить, нет ли в сессии сообщения, и если есть - вывести его, а потом удалить из сессии

Comment: Да, вот такой способ помог, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

1. Отправлять форму через AJAX
2. После отправки формы делать редирект на `ваш_скрипт.php?sent`, но это не самый лучший вариант

Answer (score -1):

можно попробовать, после вывода результата операции, сделать перегрузку с помощью:
 `header( "Location: ваш_скрипт.php" );
 exit();`